# Expected value for difference of two dependent random subset

Tags: pr.probability

Let $X=\{1,...,n\}$. I select $m$ values uniformly, on at a time, with replacement from $X$. Let $A$ denotes this random subset  and $|A|$ be the random variable for the number of distinct elements in $A$. I know that $E(|A|)=n(1-(1-1/n)^m)$.
Now, in the next step, I select $|A|$ values, one at a time, with replacement from $X$. Let $B$ denotes this random subset and $|B|$ be the random variable for the number of distinct elements in $B$. What is the expected value for the number of distinct elements in $B$ and $B-A$? Is this true that 
$$E(|B-A|)= E(|B|)\left(1-\frac{E(|A|)}{n}\right)?$$